# Help finding altitude(h) and the lenght of a side- inscribed regular pyramid

Tags: calculus, geometry

So let S be a sphere with R as it's radius. So i wanna know what is the lenght of a side and altitude/height of a 4 sided regualr pyramid that's inscribed in the before mentioned sphere, such that the volume of pyramid will be the largest

So i am looking for a solution with calculus, so i need to find lenght and height somehow described with R.

So i knwo i have to express those sides and height with soem functions, and use derivatives, but i'm stuck at finidng an expression.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $s$ and $h$ be the side and height of the pyramid. On the bottom of the pyramid, denote by $x$ half of the diagonal of the square. So $x^2=\frac{s^2}{2}$ and we have $$x^2+(h-R)^2=R^2$$ or $$s^2=h(4R-2h)$$ which is what you need to relate the volume of the pyramid to $h$ and $R$. The volume of pyramid is $$V=\frac{s^2h}{3}=\frac{h^2(4R-2h)}{3}$$ set $\frac{dV}{dh}=0$ to get $8Rh-6h^2=0$ or $$h=\frac{4}{3}R$$ This also implies $$s=\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}R^2-\frac{32}{9}R^2}=\frac{4}{3}R$$